# Validating correct spelling of user input in Python

Tags: python

How would a computer program deal with user misspelling of words in such a way that forces them to reenter until it is correct? e.g. Entering Male and Female for a gender argument.  I'm using this Python code:

```
def mean(values):

    length = len(values)

    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(length):
        total_sum += values[i]

    total_sum = sum (values)
    average = total_sum*1.0/length
    return average

name = " "
Age = " "
Gender = " "
people = []
ages = []
while  name != "":

### This is the Raw data input portion and the ablity to stop the program    and exit
    name = input("Enter a name or type done:")
    if name == 'done' : break
    Age = int(input('How old are they?'))

  Gender = input("What is their gender Male or Female?")


### This is where I use .append to create the entry of the list     
people.append(name)
people.append(Age)
ages.append(Age)
people.append(Gender)
### print("list of People:", people)

#### useing the . count to call how many  m of F they are in the list 

print ("Count for Males is : ", people.count('Male'))
print ("Count for Females is : ", people.count('Female'))

### print("There ages are",ages)

### This is where I put the code to find the average age

x= (ages)

n = mean(x)

print ("The average age is:", n)
```

I would like to also force an age in the 18-25 range.

Comment: Have you tried using nested `while` loops?

Comment: Check if name isn't `Male` or `Female` in a nested while loop then repeat

Answer (score 1):

> "... that forces them to **reenter** until it is correct?... "

Since you also asked for a way to re-enter, the following snippet uses an escape sequence of the form `\033[<N>A` which [moves the cursor **up** N lines](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) and the [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) escape sequence, `\r`,  to print over the invalid data and take input again.

```
import sys

age = 0
gender = ""

agePrompt = "How old are they? "
genderPrompt = "What is their gender Male or Female? "

#Input for age
print("")
while not ( 18 <= age <= 25 ):
    sys.stdout.write( "\033[1A\r" + " " * (len(agePrompt) + len(str(age))) )
    sys.stdout.write( "\r" + agePrompt )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    age=int(input())

#Input for gender
print("")
while not ( gender == "Male" or gender == "Female" ) :
    sys.stdout.write( "\033[1A\r" + " " * (len(genderPrompt) + len(str(gender))) )
    sys.stdout.write( "\r" + genderPrompt )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    gender=str(input())
```

Another solution would be to use the escape sequence of the form `\033[<N>D` which [moves the cursor **backward** N columns](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just keep looping until they give a valid input. Do the same for the gender.

```
Age = ""
while True:
  Age = int(input('How old are they?'))
  if int(Age) >= 18 and int(Age) <= 25:
    break
```

Comment: what other code can be used instead of continue it doesn't work right and wont lop back to the top

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a while operator that continues until you have satisfied the condition you wish be satisfied.

```
 Gender = ""
    while Gender != "Male" or Gender != "Female":
        Gender = raw_input("What is your gender, Male or Female?")
```